# How many hyperplanes does it take to separate $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Tags: combinatorics, convex-analysis, combinatorial-geometry

By 'separate', I mean that each point lies in its own little region/cell.

For instance, it takes a minimum of $P = 4$ lines to separate $n = 7$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ($m=2$), assuming that no 3 points lie on a single line (i.e. are in general position):

[image: Regular heptagon]
(*Regular heptagon*)

Now, in general, at least how many hyperplanes $P(m, n)$ does it take to separate $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^m$ (assuming general position)?

Comment: My intuition says the is an $\Bbb R^2$ problem-that in $\Bbb R^n$ the hardest problem will be if all the points are in a plane (or so close it doesn't matter)

Comment: Conjecture. A maximal number of hyperplanes is needed when there exists a convex body containing all the points on its boundary.

Comment: There is a trivial upper bound $P(m,n)\le n-1$. Morever, using an injective projection onto a hyperlance we should obtain an upper bound $P(m,n)\le P(m-1,n)$ for all $m\ge 2$.

Comment: If $m=2$ and all points are vertices of a convex polyhon, then each separating line can interect the doundary of the polyhon in at most two points. This should yield the bound $P(2,n)\ge\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$.

Comment: Even a bound $P(2,n)\ge\lceil n/2 \rceil$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky:  I think that is an answer-clearly we can do it in $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ and you need that.  We haven't shown that this suffices if they are not on a line, but I suspect so.

Comment: The another trivial lower bound should be $P(m,n)\ge\lceil log_2 n\rceil$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Can you show that $P(2,n)\le\lceil n/2\rceil$?

Comment: @AlexRavsky:  each line can split two pairs of points (as they are not collinear).

Comment: Conjecture 2. $P(m,n)=\lceil \log_2 n\rceil$ provided $n=m+1$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9086/discussion-between-ross-millikan-and-alex-ravsky)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was considered by Ralph P. Boland  and  Jorge Urrutia in the paper “[Separating  Collections of Points in Euclidean Spaces](http://www.matem.unam.mx/urrutia/online_papers/SeparPoints.pdf)”. I don't read this paper yet. As I understood, the authors showed that $$\lceil (n-1)/m\rceil\le P(m,n)\le \lceil(n-2^{\lceil\log m\rceil})/m\rceil+\lceil\log m\rceil,$$ and $P(2,n)=\lceil n/2\rceil$.

Comment: Just to be clear, I presume that's $\log$ base 2?

Comment: I don’t know, I hope this can be clarified from the paper. The pdf-file which I found has problems with the fonts, it even has no "$\le$" in the above bounds. :-(

Comment: When I called it up it displays fine.  I don't see why the dimension matters, as in higher dimension than $2$ I can always choose the points to lie in a plane.  Maybe they prohibit that just like we prohibited all the points lying on one line.

Comment: Yes, as in the notion of *general position*. Clearly, it requires more lines to separate collinear points. In particular, points in general position in $\mathbb{R^{m-1}}$ when viewed in $\mathbb{R^{m}}$ lie on a plane, which is no longer in general position (and is removed from consideration). Hence @AlexRavsky's deduction $P(m,n)≤P(m−1,n)$.

Comment: The paper appeared in Information Processing Letters; Volume 53, Issue 4, 24 February 1995, Pages 177–183, [DOI: 10.1016/0020-0190(94)00186-3](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(94)00186-3). The pdf-file from the website journal seems to be different from the one in your link, so hopefully there are no problems with the font in that file. In case you do not have access to the paper, feel free to email me and I can send you the pdf-file.